# How to prevent XSS vulnerability from being introduced when using .val()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xss

I store unsanitized user input in my database, then escape it on output.

If I enter `"><svg/onload=alert(3)>` into an input and save it in the database, then load a page that escapes the data, putting it back into the input, the page source shows:

```
... value="&quot;&gt;&lt;svg/onload=alert(3)&gt;" ...
```

As you can see, it's escaped.

However, If I then run this code:

```
$(".somediv").html($("#myinput").val());
```

Then the following is put into the element:

```
""><svg/onload=alert(3)>"
```

And the alert box pops up.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mLcLe4Lc/)

What am I doing wrong here? I thought escaping my data on output was all I needed to do, but apparently when manipulating the DOM with jQuery that's not true.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/html-encoding-in-javascript-jquery

Comment: you can use `div.innerHTML=str` instead of `$(div).html(str)` to avoid execution of scripts and keep formatting, but you still need to watch for inline event handlers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to set text, use `.text()`. The entities in the attribute’s value are already interpreted, and `""><svg/onload=alert(3)>"` *is* the value of the attribute.

```
$(".somediv").text($("#myinput").val());
```

```js
$('#destination').text($('#source').attr('title'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="source" title="&amp;&quot;&lt;">Hover over me!</div>

<div id="destination"></div>
```